# how to fix something in actual git branch state without loosing my custom code modifications, and without doing merge?

Tags: git

When I am about to commit lot of code (but not finished yet), and working in actual branch which my colleague also working on, he makes commit first, and asks me to fix something in my part of code.

So i need to pull from this branch and do merge, commit and etc.

I am not ready to do merge right now as my code is not ready, but it is required to make corrections ASAP. So in such cases i am just making clone of the last repo state in separate directory, make changes and push in back.

There is some more elegant solution in such cases (without stash/pop, cause i need to continue working on my code and not merge it right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *stash* your changes

```
git stash
```

this will save all changes and reset the workspace to a clean state. You can then pull in their changes

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

and can fix their problems.

Afterwards you can apply your stashed changes using

```
git stash pop
```

and continue with your own work.

Comment: if i changed the same file, in which colleague made modifications doesnt `stash pop` will force me to do merge ?

Comment: Depends, if the changes were in the same file but not touching the same lines it will be done without your help, if you both changed the same lines you `git` will ask you to resolve it.